# cookie not being set when Expires less than 1 year, on localhost (Chrome and FF)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, firefox, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm facing a problem on localhost, and in `Chrome` and `Firefox`, not `Edge`

this code will work ok, and will set the cookie:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Change(string val)
{
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName) { Value = val, Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) };

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    return Content("");
}
```

however if I change the Expires  to just `300 days`, the cookie won't be sent back in the `Request Cookies`, (it will still be visible in the `Response Cookies` for the `Change` request)

**Edit:**
this action is called via jquery ajax (`$.post`); and it used to work maybe half a year ago

Comment: This is weird, works fine for me:


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Change(string val)
        {
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie") { Value = val, Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(300) };

            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            return Content("<a href=\"Check\"> a </a>");
        }

        public ActionResult Check()
        {
            var cookies = Request.Cookies;
            return View();
        }

Comment: So you can consistently reproduce it even with simple mvc application with just that method above? Or only on some more complex than that?

Comment: @Evk yes, it's the same behavior for me in 2 projects, on localhost; works on edge though

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put cookie.Domain = null on localhost and use the domain name otherwise.